# Angular 6 - How to define return value type with more than 1 type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a return function in Angular 6, and I want to define the return value type. But the problem is, my function can be used in several cases, and the return value is based on the case.
Here is my code below:

```
updateProcess(type, list, event: {}) {
    let newList = [];
    switch (event["action"]) {
        case ListManipulation.Add:
            newList = list;
            newList.push(event["data"]);
            break;
        case ListManipulation.Delete:
            newList = list.filter(
                setting => !event["data"].includes(setting[this.itemProperties[type]["idName"]])
            );
            break;
        default:
            newList = list;
            break;
    }
    return [...newList];
}
```

and suppose you have one type for the return value, you can do it like this:

```
updateProcess(type, list, event: {}): string {
```

But what I want to do is:

```
updateProcess(type, list, event: {}): string | [] | {} {
```

Can anyone help?

PS. Also I need that for type of ***list*** as parameter

Comment: but it 's look like you just return array of any   `return [...newList];`

Comment: Simply specify all the possible types seperated by pipe `(ex : string[] | string)`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type base on all other types and used like normal type

```
type specialType = string  | {} | any[];
```

and use it like this

```
updateProcess(type, list : specialType , event: {}) : specialType   {
    let newList = [];
    switch (event["action"]) {
        case ListManipulation.Add:
            newList = list;
            newList.push(event["data"]);
            break;
        case ListManipulation.Delete:
            newList = list.filter(
                setting => !event["data"].includes(setting[this.itemProperties[type]["idName"]])
            );
            break;
        default:
            newList = list;
            break;
    }
    return [...newList];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm pretty new with Angular and I don't really know how to use that. _**type**_ specialType = string  | {} | any[]; gives error.

Comment: Yes, but it still gives error to declare the specialType. I tried to import Type too.
2 questions: I need to declare it as normal variable right? And should I import certain thing?

Comment: just create a typescript file and exported like this export type specialType = string  | {} | any[];